# vmin on width and height not consistent for td element

Tags: html, css

[on my site](http://boogerlad.github.io/othello/) I'm trying to create a scalable ui othello game. Each piece of the board should be a square. I'm using tables as the markup for the board. The css I'm using is

```
#board td
{
    background: #C38147;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12vmin;
    height: 12vmin;
}
```

The width and the height should be the same, but the inspector shows otherwise...[image: screenshot]

I've tried removing the x marks in hopes that they would be overflowing, but no dice.

Comment: unclear what the q is - they are square what's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to the world of sub-pixel rendering and viewport units.

Comment: The squares are 123x122 pixels. Is this problem unavoidable then?

Comment: they're pretty cool units, but somewhat unreliable, I always use the padding-bottom trick, or provide a fallback in css

Comment: and i have just checked your screen grab for embarrassing tabs :-P

Comment: eh, I've got nothing to hide

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `padding-bottom`?

By setting padding-bottom to be the same as width a square can be created, then by setting the widths to a % they can be made responsive:

```
.element {
    width: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}
```

Have a look at the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/p934a15n/1/)

Also, you may well fair better using `<div>`s rather than `<table>` - tables have some funny rendering issues in various contexts and can be difficult to work with.

As you are using tables, you may want add in `border-collapse: collapse;` on the `<table>` tag and `display: inline-block;` on the cells.

Comment: That's very interesting. I understand the width being 10% is of the parent container, but what does 10% for padding-bottom mean? Where is that number derived from?

Comment: it's basically the same as the width so a square is created. You could do 5%, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p934a15n/2/) which creates an oblong half as deep as it is wide. Bear in mind it's the ratio between width and padding-bottom that creates the shape